# Seekbar not working

Tags: android, seekbar

I found some code for a seekbar to work with a mediaplayer online:

```
 @Override
 public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

 }

 @Override
 public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
     // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
     mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
 }
 @Override
 public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
     mHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
     int totalDuration = mp.getDuration();
     int currentPosition = utils.progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);

     // forward or backward to certain seconds
     mp.seekTo(currentPosition);

     // update timer progress again
     updateProgressBar();
 }
```

I get an error because of the Override's, telling me that they must override or implement a supertype method. When I remove them, my code compiles and runs but the seekbar has no affiliation with the music playing, as in I can move it around but the music keeps playing.

Thanks.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); //this line causes an error
        try {
            mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_MUSIC).getPath() + "/SpaceJam.mp3");
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            mp.prepare();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart(){
        super.onStart();

        btnPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_pause);
        btnStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);
        songTitleLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.songname);
        songTitleArtist = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.artist);
        songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.current);
        songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.total);
        albumArt = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.albumArt);
        res = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.album_art);
        utils = new Utilities();
        . . .
}
```

Comment: A quick question, Has your class implented "SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener". If not you need to implement it and bring back the @override annotation.

Comment: also, could you show a bit more of the code surrounding these override methods?

Comment: When I added "seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);", I get the error: The method setOnSeekBarChangeListener(SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener) in the type SeekBar is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity)

Comment: Read this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Comment: I am facing issue with SeekBar can you please help me... here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54692981/android-music-seekbar-is-not-working-idle

Answer (score 1):

As prijupaul mentioned, you must to implement `OnSeekBarChangeListener`. change your code as follow:

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnSeekBarChangeListener
 {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          ...
          seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
          ...
     }

     @Override
     public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromTouch) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

     }

     @Override
     public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

     }
 }
```